# QGIS 3.22 zooming pans map incorrectly to the right

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, zoom, macos

I've come across this issue when trying to zoom in OSM.

Here is a video of the issue:

https://i.imgur.com/emqxC7S.mp4

I don't have it when using the QGIS world map. Basically zooming straight in without moving my mouse in any direction move the location on the map to the right.

I'm new to QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced this bug with **QGIS 3.22**, too (running OSX Catalina). It has nothing to do with your OSX version. I downgraded to [**QGIS 3.16 LTR**](https://qgis.org/downloads/macos/qgis-macos-ltr.dmg) which doesn't show this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! It worked with QGIS 3.16. Hope the bug will get fixed.